# How to keep the camera view to within room dimensions

Tags: camera, game-maker

```
    me = self;
    view_yview[0] += ( me.y-(view_hview[0]/2) - view_yview[0]) * 0.1;
    view_xview[0] += ( me.x-(view_wview[0]/2) - view_xview[0]) * 0.3;
```

This is the code I use to smooth camera movement in game maker. But it's going beyond the room dimensions; showing stuff that shouldn't be shown, as the camera should stop following the player at a point.

How do I achieve this?

Comment: I suggest that you give far more details than that so people familiar with game-maker can jump in with a proper answer. Per your code snippet, it is a 2D game. But is the camera isometric-positioned? Does the player move in 360 degrees, or 8 directions or 4 directions? Is it grid based? What is the code that is moving the camera? The camera should stop when the player is out of the room?

Answer (score 1):

Try adding:

```
view_xview[0] = round(median(0, room_width - view_wview[0] - 1, view_xview[0]));
view_yview[0] = round(median(0, room_height - view_hview[0] - 1, view_yview[0]));
```

and you need not use `me` and `self`:

```
view_xview[0] += (x - view_wview[0] / 2 - view_xview[0]) * 0.3;
view_yview[0] += (y - view_hview[0] / 2 - view_yview[0]) * 0.1;
```